# My css code is not working as i want, it will not show images

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code does not work properly and I shall have to ask you to look away from the obvious lack of a proper url and email adress. I am trying to get a photo to be switched out with another one, as soon as I hover the mouse above it. Also I want it to be a active photo, so when I click it I get an email pop-up window.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <div>
       <br/>
    </div>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .imgBox1
    {
      width: 333px;
      height: 416px;
      background-image: url(DSC_0267-Edit.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
    .imgBox1:hover
    {
      width: 333px;
      height: 416px;
      background-image: url(DSC_0267-Edit-Edit%202.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="mailto:x@x.com">
    <div class="imgBox1">
    </div>
    </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sooooo, what doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you have a `div` before the `html` tag?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `a:hover .imgBox1 { }`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <div>
       <br/>
    </div>
    <html> Please make it correct remove div before Html tag .

Answer (score 1):

change css to use background from background-image. Checkout background CSS rules [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background) for more information.

```css
.imgBox1 {
  width: 333px;
  height: 416px;
  background: url(https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png) no-repeat;
}
.imgBox1:hover {
  width: 333px;
  height: 416px;
  background-image: url(https://s.yimg.com/rz/l/yahoo_en-US_f_p_142x37_2x.png);
}
```

```html
<a href="mailto:x@x.com">
  <div class="imgBox1"></div>
</a>
```